# Resolve Hold-Up Problems in Joint Investment

Tags: game-theory

Say two agents jointly invest with a return function $f(i_1, i_2)$, which is increasing in both and concave, and they share the return by ratio $\beta_1$ and $1-\beta_1$.

Then the result of investment level will be the solution of $\beta_1 f_1(i_1, i_2^*)=mc_1$ and $(1-\beta_1) f_2(i_1^*, i_2)=mc_2$. And these investments will be inefficient: if all agents increase their investment by a little, it will make both better off.

This is different from the one-side hold-up problems because we can never given the full claimant on residual to both side to solve the incentive problem, and I somehow feel this is like a continuous version of  the Prisoner's Dilemma (Is there a formal name?). I think this general form is very common in the real world. I wonder do we have ways to resolve this holdup problem other than putting it into an infinite repeated horizon?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but I don’t understand why this would be common in the real world. Shouldn’t the share depend on investment?

Comment: @LudwigNagasena For example you and your colleague jointly do a project in the firm. It is not easy for your supervisor to detect individual effort and the share is often decided by some pre-determined rule.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement investment levels that leave both better off than before, and if the output is contractible, then you can write a contract with a third party that will receive the whole output unless it reaches at least the prescribed level.

Say, you want to induce $i_1^*$ and $i_2^*$, and both are better off investing this much than not participating. Assume also that at these investment levels, the individual marginal benefit is smaller than the marginal cost.

Now, if the output is at least $f(i_1^*,i_2^*)$, the whole output is transferred to a third party, who will gladly accept it. They cannot lose. Then none of these two firms has an incentive to produce more or less than the prescribed investment level.

The argument relies of course on production being deterministic and output being fully contractible. I do not claim that this is always the best approach "in reality."